# Text Argument in R Function With GLM: Object Not Found

Tags: r, parsing, eval, glm

A function included in a package is throwing an error when I attempt to supply weights to the function. The portion of the package call is required to be specified like this:

```
weights = c("kernel_wght")
```

Inside the function, the following two lines of code are used to specify a data frame object called weight:

```
weight1 <- sprintf("dataarg$%s", weights)
weight <- as.data.frame(eval(parse(text = weight1)))
```

However, the analytic portion of the function attempts to use glm to conduct an analysis of data, using the weights provided.

```
result1 <- glm(f1, family="gaussian", weights=weight, data=dataarg)
```

Doing so yields the following error:

```
Error in (function (arg) : object 'weight' not found
```

I've seen some recommendations that the whole glm call should be re-specified...and i've seen some referrals to global environment objects. Why can i print the dataframe, verifying it indeed is created, but can't refer to it in the call to glm? Is there a fix that i have overlooked?

As per requested, here is a small example. I created some sample data, as if it had come from a multiple imputation generating process:

```
dat <- c(1, 1, 0, .5, 1, 3, 0,  1, 1, 4, 0, .5, 1, 5, 1,  1, 1, 2, 1, 
 .5,
     2, 7, 1,  1, 2, 3, 0, .5, 2, 2, 0,  1, 2, 4, 1, .5)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(dat,ncol=4, byrow=T))
colnames(dat) <- c("id", "y", "tx", "wt")

imp_lst <- lapply(1:2, function(s) dplyr::filter(dat, id == s))
for (i in 1:length(imp_lst)) { assign(paste0("imp", i), 
as.data.frame(imp_lst[[i]])) }

df_lst <- list()
for (i in 1:length(imp_lst)) { 
  assign(paste0("imp", i), as.data.frame(imp_lst[[i]]))
  df_lst <- append(df_lst, list(get(paste0("imp", i))))
  names(df_lst)[i] <- paste0("imp", i)
}
```

And here is a small example, mostly taken from the package, that re-creates the problem:

```
my_ex <- function(datasets, y, treatment, weights=NULL, ...) {
 data <- names(datasets)

  for (i in 1:length(treatment)) {
    d1 <- sprintf("datasets$%s", data[i])
    dataarg <- eval(parse(text=d1))
    print(dataarg)

    if(!is.null(weights)) {
      weight1 <- sprintf("dataarg$%s", weights)
      weight <- as.data.frame(eval(parse(text = weight1)))
      print(weight)
    } else {
      dataarg$weight <- weight <- rep(1,nrow(dataarg))
    }

  f1 <- sprintf("%s ~ %s ", y, treatment)
  print(f1)
  result1 <- glm(f1, family="gaussian", weights=weight, data=dataarg)
  print(summary(result1))
  }
}
```

Using the following call, the error appears:

```
testrun <- my_ex(df_lst, y = c("y","y"), treatment = c("tx","tx"), weights = c("wt","wt"))enter code here
```

Comment: You should put together a reproducible example.  We don't have enough code to do anything.

Comment: We definitely need more information. `set.seed(101); mtcars$wt <- runif(nrow(mtcars)); weightvar <- "mtcars$wt"; weight <- as.data.frame(eval(parse(text = weightvar))); glm(mpg ~ hp, family = "gaussian", weights = weight, data = mtcars)` gives "invalid type (list) for variable '(weights)'". If I leave out the `as.data.frame` it works. One guess:  where does `f1` come from? If it is generated within a different scope (e.g. it is an object returned from a function) it carries its own (different) environment along, which may confuse R ...

Comment: @BenBolker i do think the problem has to do with f1 in glm. I included PRINT calls along the way and everything seems to be ok until you hit the glm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proximal problem is that you are defining the formula as a character string and passing it to `glm`.  It gets converted to a formula within `glm`, but when that happens its environment is the environment of `glm`, so it doesn't know where to look for the `weights` variable (loosely speaking, `glm` will look (1) within the data frame provided as `data` and (2) in the environment of the formula).  You can work around this by using `as.formula()` to convert the string to a formula before passing it to `glm` (e.g. `glm(as.formula(f1), ...)`).

**However**: using functions like `eval`, `parse`, `assign` is a *code smell*  in R — it means there's probably a more natural, simpler, more robust way to do what you want. For example, I think this function does the same as what your function is trying to do, relying on indexing within lists rather than using `eval(parse(...))` and friends.

```r
my_ex2 <- function(datasets, y, treatment,  weights = NULL, ...) {
    result <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(treatment)) {
        form <- reformulate(treatment[i], response = y[i])
        data <- datasets[[i]]
        ## note double brackets around second term - we want
        ## the results to be a vector, not a data frame
        weight <- data[[weights[i]]]
        result[[i]] <- glm(formula = form, weight = weight, data = data)
    }
    result
}
```

Then, to print out all the summaries, `lapply(result, summary)` (if you really think you only need the summary, you can save the summary instead of the fitted object inside the loop).